# C# xaml call method in another page - process field data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame

I have situation, where I have `MainPage`, which has `Frame` in it and a button.

`Button` is there to navigate through different pages to fill up form.

`Frame` is there to display these pages with different forms and data to insert.

Now I have a problem, if I press that button, I need to process that data on that page, where I am at. Edited (working) code:

```
SubjectInfo si;
NeckPain np;
...

private void Navigate()
        {
            step++;
            if (action.Equals("New"))
            {
                if (si == null)
                LoadNewSubjectPages();
                switch (step)
                {
                    case 1:
                        ShowFrame();  // Frame becomes visible to display pages
                        FrameMain.Navigate(si); // Displays subject info page in frame
                        btnNavigation.Content = "Next";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        bool res = si.ValuesToExcel(); // Problematic place (1) - Fixed
                        if (res)
                            FrameMain.Navigate(np);
                        else
                            step--;
                        break;
                        ...
                    default:  // When steps reach to end
                        HideFrame();
                        LoadNewSubjectPages(); // Loads new Page objects
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
// Loads pages for form.
private void LoadNewSubjectPages()
        {
            si = new SubjectInfo();
            np = new NeckPain();
            ...
        }
```

`(1)` Here is where I call that method on page, but every element in that page is empty. So when I get for example `txbName.Text` all I get is `null`.

How Can I get that Page with all the filled fields?

Edit: Maybe there is better way to solve this, but that is how I edited this at the moment.

Comment: Are you creating a new SubjectInfo any time that you press the button?

Comment: You are correct, my bad.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `SubjectInfo` any time that you press the button. Create it out of `Navigate()` and all will be correct.